# Monkey patching C extension in Python

Tags: python, psycopg2, monkeypatching, python-c-extension, python-extensions

Using the method discussed in [question 972](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object), I was unable to monkey patch the cursor() method in psycopg:

Tried to patch a methond in psycopg2 with *types* but it did not work:

```
>>> import psycopg2, types
import psycopg2, types
>>> db = psycopg2.connect('dbname=foo')
db = psycopg2.connect('dbname=foo')
>>> def mycursor(self):
def mycursor(self):
...     db.rollback()
    db.rollback()
...     return self.cursor()
    return self.cursor()
... 

>>> db.mycursor = types.MethodType(mycursor, db)
db.mycursor = types.MethodType(mycursor, db)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'psycopg2._psycopg.connection' object has no attribute 'mycursor'
>>>
```

Is it because it's a C extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. Types defined in C cannot have arbitrary attributes added.